# $S$-affine prescheme associated to an $\mathscr{O}_S$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am having some trouble following the argument in EGA (II, 1.3.1).  Let $S$ be a prescheme and $\mathcal{B}$ a quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_S$-algebra.  Define for an affine open subset $U \subset S$ the $S$-prescheme $X_U = \operatorname{Spec}(\Gamma(U, \mathcal{B}))$.  Then he says it follows from (I, 1.3.7), (I, 1.3.13) and (I, 1.6.3) that $\mathcal{A}(X_U) = \mathcal{B}|_U$, where $\mathcal{A}(X_U)$ is the direct image by $X_U \to U$, viewed as an $\mathscr{O}_S|_U$-module.

Here is what I can see: Let $\Psi = (^a \phi, \tilde{\phi}) : (X_U, \mathscr{O}_{X_U}) \to (U, \mathscr{O}_S|_U)$ be the morphism induced by the homomorphism $\phi : A' = \Gamma(U, \mathscr{O}_S) \to A = \Gamma(U, \mathcal{B})$.  Now we have

$$\mathcal{A}(X_U) = \Psi_\ast(\mathscr{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)}) = \Psi_\ast(\tilde{A}).$$

By (I, 1.6.3), we have a canonical isomorphism $\widetilde{A_{[\phi]}} = \Psi_{\ast}(\tilde{A})$, where $A_{[\phi]}$ is $A$ viewed as an $A'$-module via $\phi$.  (I, 1.3.13) gives $\widetilde{A_{[\phi]}}$ an $\mathscr{O}_S|_U$-module structure.  We can look at the sections over some $D(f) \subset U$ ($f \in A'$):

$$\Gamma(D(f), \mathcal{A}(X_U)) = \Gamma(D(f), \widetilde{A_{[\phi]}}) = (A_{[\phi]})_f = A_{\phi(f)}$$

by (I, 1.3.7).  On the other hand, since $\mathcal{B}$ is quasi-coherent, we have $B|_U = \tilde{M}$ for some $A'$-module $M$.  Therefore

$$\Gamma(D(f), \mathcal{B}) = \Gamma(D(f), \tilde{M}) = M_f$$

again by (I, 1.3.7).

Now I don't see how to identify $A_{\phi(f)}$ and $M_f$.  Am I missing something about quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_S$-algebras?

Comment: I think the chapter numbers are incorrect.

Comment: I have the 1960 edition from NUMDAM (not the 1971 revision).

Comment: Me, too. I think you mean EGA (II, 1.3.1) for example.

Comment: Sorry, all the volume numbers were shifted by 1.

Comment: Dear Adeel, When you write $U \subset X$, do you mean $U \subset S$?  Regards,

Comment: Matt: Yes, sorry!